# Use v-model to search in v-for array - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

It's been a long time since I build something with Vue.js. I am building just a simple app that's rendering some items with a `v-for` from an array. I want to use a input box with a `v-model` to search in the list of items (presets).

Code

```html
<div class="row top20">
    <div class="col-md-3" v-for="preset in presets">
        <div class="template-block" :id="preset.id">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" v-bind:alt="preset.img" class="img img-responsive img-template">
            <h3>{{ preset.presetName }}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Data

```
searchQuery: '',
presets: [
    {id: '2', presetName: 'WooCommerce', img: 'woocommerce.png'},
    {id: '3', presetName: 'Magento', img: 'magento.png'},
    {id: '1', presetName: 'Custom', img: 'custom.png'}
]
```

So I tried something like `<div class="col-md-3" v-for="preset in presets | searchQuery">` and other things like that but that don't seem to work. I thought of using a computed property but since I don't exactly know how they work I haven't figured it out. Is there someone with a fast and easy solution?

**Edit**

I've figured out that I can use a method to search. But the problem with that is that it will only display the results of a exactly match. What I would like is that If I type something and the letters are included in the name it will still display the items that (for a part) match.

Method

```
methods: {
    filterItems: function(presets) {
        var app = this;
        return presets.filter(function(preset) {
            return preset.presetName == app.searchQuery;
        })
    }
}
```

Edited view

```html
<div class="col-md-3" v-for="preset in filterItems(presets)" :key="preset.presetName">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) for that:

```
filterItems: function(presets) {
  var app = this;
  return presets.filter(function(preset) {
    let regex = new RegExp('(' + app.searchQuery + ')', 'i');
    return preset.presetName.match(regex);
  })
}
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u2vsbkap/

Answer (score 1):

The filter input like：

```
<input type="text" v-model="searchQuery" />
```

then modify the function:

```
filterItems: function(presets) {
var searchQuery = this.searchQuery;
var reg;

if (searchQuery === '') {
    return presets;
}
return presets.filter(function(preset) {
  return preset.presetName.indexOf(searchQuery) >= 0;
})
```

}

Comment: Good solution except it's not the best option I guess; If the name is "WooCommerce" and the query is "woocommerce" It will unf. not match. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that,(:-

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I found this great repo on github https://github.com/freearhey/vue2-filters.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue2-filters/dist/vue2-filters.min.js"></script>
```

or

npm install vue2-filters

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vue2Filters from 'vue2-filters'

Vue.use(Vue2Filters)
```

Code

```
<div class="col-md-3" v-for="preset in filterBy(presets, searchQuery)">
```